# Virtual Machine Share license with Host?

Tags: windows, virtualization, vps

I have a really old accounting software that my client uses on their server (windows), the product provider no longer exists and so we can't get new licenses from it.

I have a working copy on the server and was wondering if there was away to use VMware or some similar software to clone the server to add virtual machines that users could log into and still access the software at the same time without it prompting us for other license keys?

Since it would still be on the same physical host and users would access it via VPS (and because the software is abandon ware) it's technically legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can migrate an existing physical machine to a VM

VMware -- http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/

Virtualbox -- https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows

Make sure you have backups before attempting any of the above.

Comment: But this would allow me to have multiple virtual run the software multiple times on an individual license?

Comment: I'm not sure how the licensing works for your old accounting software. But once you create an VM "image" of your existing physical server, you can "clone" the VM's as many times as you want to new VM's. Yes, if your license is tied to a single host, then you can run multiple VM's on the same license.